# Tag for standard use of SharePoint

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a tag to cover things that are about regular OOTB SharePoint use? I'm not trying to do anything fancy, I'm stuck on something so obvious there doesn't seem to be anywhere explaining how to do it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an [ootb](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ootb) tag (out of the box), https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags/ootb/info.